# Port doesn't open on Linux server when spinning up a docker container

Tags: docker, port

I am trying to spin up a docker container on an Ubuntu server using the following command:

```
docker run -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=username -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -e POSTGRES_DB=falafel postgres
```

and the port 5432 doesn't get opened on localhost. When I run the same command on my local machine (Macbook M1) the port gets opened as expected. This is the output of `docker ps` and `nmap`:
[image]

I don't have root permissions but I am in the docker group. I can open ports when not dealing with dockerized applications just fine. I tried restarting the docker daemon.

Anyone knows what might be the issue?

Comment: btw, if docker is running in rootful mode (default case) and you are part of the docker group/you can control the docker daemon, you almost have "root" permissions. You can find more information here https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a collision of 2 docker services: `docker-netns.service` and `docker.service`. This made it look like the docker is correctly running but since I was not supposed to user the `docker.service` the port got exposed in global network and not in "my" network.  After stopping and disabling `docker.service` and restarting `docker-netns.service` everything works as expected.